# Mongo to convert timestamp to numeric value to use with $divide

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion

I want to use timestamp value as an integer value i.e. the total number of seconds/milliseconds (the converted timestamp value into seconds/milliseconds) and use it with [$divide accumulator/operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#exp._S_divide)

I tried that as [this code](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/commit/5b3e55ab0149ab387895b44c754e501c7b24e0b2) but get error

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $divide only supports numeric types, not date and int

I [google](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=mongo+convert+datetime+to+int&oq=mongo+convert+datetime+to+int&aqs=chrome..69i57.1203j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for convert datetime to int though get little helpful result

So how can we get around it i.e. to get $divide work with timestamp?

Comment: have you tried ? `{$divide:[{$millisecond:"$ts"}, 1]}`

Comment: So, the $millisecond is the **total milliseconds** not the millisecond within the $minute, isn't it?

Comment: I tried $millisecond as [here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/commit/cbfc16e956a61625d1b4edf28841e6617ffd96e7), and results as 0 which means $millisecond is the within-$minute, not the total millisecond

Comment: Sorry you are right. It is the milliseconds of minute and indeed there is no way to do such type conversion available yet. Can we change the second argument to be a timestamp ? What does 1 mean there ? What kind of values does second argument take ?

Comment: I want to sample/decrease the number of documents returned from my mongo query i.e. the `2nd param` as `1` means some threshold. So we need **total second** as 1st param and some numeric value as 2nd param for $divide operator

Comment: You can see what I'm trying to do with sampling [here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/blob/master/query-tutorial.python/04a_datetime.py) @Veeram

Comment: There I have to calculate the workaround for year, dayOfYear as doy, secondOfDay as sod, and then to group by year, doy, sod/threshold. A much simpler query would be available if we have conversion from datetime to numeric value available.